# Processing text that sits between two nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an XML that contains some text:

```
<p>Sentence blah blah blah <a_href=... />,<a_href=... />,<a_href=... />.</p>
```

The a_href tags will be output as superscripts (using a CSS that sets the superscript for the a_href tag), and I want the commas between the a_href elements to get a superscript as well. So I'm looking for a transformation with this result:

```
<p>Sentence blah blah blah <a_href... /><sup>,</sup><a_href... /><sup>,</sup><a_href... />.</p>
```

I don't think I can use Xpath to select only part of the text node, so there's no way to find "an a_href tag followed by a comma and another a_href tag". 
I can check whether an a_href tag is followed by another a_href tag, but can't check what's between them? 
The superscript should happen only if there is a comma, or a comma and one space between the a_href nodes. If there's more text, it should not get a superscript.

(edit: renamed the tag to a_href to remove ambiguity, in the actual code the underscore is absent)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want only commas separating two `<a>` nodes to be tagged as `<sup>`, or any text between two such nodes? -- P.S. `href` is not a tag.

Comment: edited question to clarify

Comment: "*renamed the tag to a_href to remove ambiguity*" That makes no sense. There is no ambiguity here.  `href` is an *attribute* of the `a` *element* (anyone who has ever so much as glanced at an HTML code knows that).

Comment: I meant ambiguity in the sense of things being difficult to read when you talk about an a tag.

Comment: I am afraid you're still missing the point: you referred to `href`as a tag. I said `href` is not a tag, You should have said the `a` tag, that's all. -- More importantly: is your question answered?

Comment: I suspect it is, but can't be sure until I test it on Monday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The superscript should happen only if there is a comma, or a comma and
>   one space between the a_href nodes.

Given a well-formed (!) input such as:

**XML**

```
<p>Start <a href="abc"/>,<a href="def"/>, middle <a href="ghi"/>, <a href="jkl"/> and end.</p>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space(.)=',' and preceding-sibling::*[1][self::a] and following-sibling::*[1][self::a]]">
    <sup>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </sup>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>Start <a href="abc"/>
   <sup>,</sup>
   <a href="def"/>, middle <a href="ghi"/>
   <sup>, </sup>
   <a href="jkl"/> and end.</p>
```

---

**Note**:

You say that the `a` tags are styled as superscript by CSS; I don't know much about CSS, but I suspect it could handle this task just as well.